# How to add connection points in Visio 2013 using Vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to add connection points to a shape via Vbscript code.  The following lines are the only ones I have tried that don't cause an error but they actually don't create the connection point I am looking for.

```
Set Vapp = GetObject(,"visio.application")

Set VP = Vapp.activewindow

VP.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(26).CellsSRC(VisSectionConnectionPts,0, VisCnnctX).FormulaU = ".0815"
VP.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(26).CellsSRC(visSectionConnectionPts, 0, visCnnctY).FormulaU = ".0710"
```

It's noteworthy that using "vis" does not work in such commands as:

```
VP.Shapes.ItemFromID(26).CellsU("LineColor").Formula = "rgb(255,192,0)"
```

And notice that I had to enclose LineColor in parentheses, but that does not work with the connection point commands.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer (http://www.activecallcenter.com/manual/306.htm).

Since Vbscript does not know what Visio constants such as VisSectionConnectionPts are, I have to look up the index number for VisSectionConnectionPts in the Visio object library.  Using the index numbers for these constants works just fine.